# Rails: How to retrieve avatar from Twitter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, avatar

In an app I use authentication through Twitter and into a table I store Twitter UID.
Is there any way to display through the Twitter UID user's avatar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use their UID to get their profile information which contains the URL for their image. You can see the documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show